# using g++ compiler

Tags: compiling, g++

I have this simple program named Conversion.cc on my Desktop &.show below

```
//
// Conversion - Program to convert temperature from
//            Celsius into Fahrenheit:
//            Fahrenheit = Celsius * (212 -32)/100 +32
//
#include <studio>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int nNumberofArgs, char* pszArgs[]){
 {                                              
   // enter the temperature in Celsius
  int celsius
  cout << "Enter the temperature In Celsius:";
  cin >> celsius;
  
  calculate conversion factor for Celsius
  // to Fahrenheit
  int factor;
  factor = 212 - 32;
  
  // use conversion factor to convert Celsius
  // into Fahrenheit values 
  int fahrenheit;
  fahrenheit = factor * celsius/100 +32:
 
 //output the results (followed by a Newline)
  cout << fahrenheit value is:";
  cout << fahrenheit << end];
  
  //wait until user is ready before terminating program
  //to allow the user to see program results
  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
  }
```

I went to use g++ to compile it. the results are shown below

```
Desktop$ g++ -o Conversion Conversion.cc
Conversion.cc:6:10: fatal error: studio: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <studio>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Desktop$ g++ -o Conversion Conversion.cc
Conversion.cc:6:10: fatal error: studio: No such file or directory
    6 | #include <studio>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: The C header file is named `stdio.h` and the C++ header is [cstdio](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdio)

Comment: Make sure you *actually* specify the correct include.  `studio` is not `stdio` and if you intend to import the `stdio` library then you need to *spell* it right.  Also, FYI, pure programming questions like this probably belong on Stack Overflow, not here on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: ... I notice that your code doesn't appear to use any C-style IO functions, so you likely don't need `cstdio` anyhow